# How do I extract Joomla intro image outside intro text in order for it to show on the left of title and other info in featured page?

Tags: php, html, css, joomla, blogs

I am trying to achieve a custom layout for my featured article page on Joomla in order to make a nice blog layout with my custom design made on Photoshop.

This is the look I am trying to achieve: http://i48.tinypic.com/2ztbx54.png

This is the look I am getting at the moment: http://i49.tinypic.com/1ibn5w.png

Rest of the layout would not be a problem since it's pretty easily modifiable, however, the problem where I am stuck at the moment is the intro image. I want it to be on the left from the article title, some information and intro text like shown in the first image.

Is it possible to extract the image out of intro text in order to place it where needed?

Help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: So you're missing the "Dick/Bush" part? Hmmm

Comment: That is not the issue. It can be adjusted. Just had to think of some author name for demonstration, so I thought that if George Bush had Dick Chaney's first name, his name would be Dick Bush!

Comment: @navnav: not sure if that was a joke but couldnt help but chuckle at that. Edgar, you don't need to extract it. just tweak the styling and it should solve your problem. if you want to provide a link to the site, I will try in Firebug.

Comment: @EdgarRitman: The problem is, you have all the content in 1 column. Try have the image in column 1 with a left float, and the text on column 2 with a right float.

Comment: How do I make it in two columns? Do you mean featured article columns? Because as far as I know, each column corresponds to an article and all it's information, not one article and one image in a different column. Do you have a skype account?

Comment: @EdgarRitman: Read my answer below. I think will solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, my comment was just a joke.

Now, for the question: your image is sitting in the div `item column-1` when it should be sitting in the the div above that (the container of `item column-1`) which is `items-row cols-1 row-0`.

So this:

```
<img src="/images/Articles/macbookpro-review-01-top.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="macbookpro-review-01-top" style="float: left;">
```

Cannot go in `<div class="items-row cols-1 row-0">` or `<dl class="article-info">` which is what you are currently doing.

It needs to be sitting in the outer div. So it should be in `<div class="items-row cols-1 row-0">`. So like this:

```
<div class="items-row cols-1 row-0">
  <img src="/images/Articles/macbookpro-review-01-top.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="macbookpro-review-01-top" style="float: left;">
//...and the rest of your stuff
```

Comment: at first I thought it had to be outside there was another way around it.

Comment: Well that is obvious, if it was that simple I would have done just that, but how do I get the image outside when it's dynamic not static like in Joomla?

Comment: I've never worked with Joomla, but show me the code that's producing this dynamic html.

Answer (score 1):

In your css file add the following code to get you started off:

```
.article-info {
    float:right;
}
h2 { 
    text-align: right; 
}
.item.column-1 img {
    margin-top: -50px;
}
.article-info-term { 
    padding-left: 40px; 
}
```

Also, take away the `margin: 0px;` you have added to the images.

This is what the result will be:

http://i735.photobucket.com/albums/ww355/lodder16/stack_image.png

Hope this helps

Comment: Seems to kinda work, but what do I do with the text now? How do I align it properly so it doesn't stick with the image?

Comment: @EdgarRitman: give the `<p>` tag a class for example `<p class="text">` then use something like `padding-left: 150px;`

Comment: Do you really think this is the best method?
IMHO it will collapse on IE.

Comment: no, it's not the best method but I am limited as I can only edit the CSS with Firebug. The best thing to do would be to have 2 columns, 1 for the image and the other for the text.

Comment: How do I manage to do that? Can you show me through Teamviewer?

Comment: Yeah, this is not what I was looking for. Have to figure out some method with PHP where I get the first image from an article and embed it outside the column div.